# Unable to uninstall appmap extension from Visual Code Studio

Tags: vscode-extensions

I installed this plugin **AppMap**, and after I uninstalled I was unable to run any junit test cases or our java app.

When I run my junit test case, I get options to Test with AppMap. I choose one of them and I get this error

> command 'appmap.getAppmapDir' not found

I uninstalled the extension and also did what some answers recommended, tried to find the extension folder in `~/.vscode/extensions` folder. Unable to find a folder with `appmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a search I realized that `launch.json` and `settings.json` had enteries for `Test with AppMap` and `Run with AppMap`. Removed those configs and things started to work again.

This has been documented in the extension documentation too [here](https://appmap.io/docs/reference/uninstalling-appmap.html#uninstalling-the-appmap-vs-code-extension), thanks @petecheslock.

Comment: Glad you were able to identify this issue. You are correct that AppMap adds those launch configurations to make it easy to run your tests with AppMap enabled.  I will add a section to our Uninstall documentation(1) to cover this issue you ran into.

1) https://appmap.io/docs/reference/uninstalling-appmap.html#uninstalling-the-appmap-vs-code-extension

Comment: Let me know when u fix it.. I will update the answer with "version" details.

Comment: Sure thing - i've updated our documentation to call out the launch configurations.  Hope this helps!

https://appmap.io/docs/reference/uninstalling-appmap.html#uninstalling-the-appmap-vs-code-extension

Comment: I did not notice the error message `command 'appmap.getAppmapDir' not found`. For clarity sake, it would be good to mention that.